# Word break in bootstrap not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to display some JSON data in a `pre` block but Bootstrap's work break doesn't seem to be working.

http://jsfiddle.net/kRAv2/

How can I make the data to be displayed in the next line instead of the same?

Comment: Use rows for bootstrap

Comment: what does that have to do with my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/v6yxe/

Bootstrap's Pre doesn't break, you have to add your own CSS.

```
pre#target {
    white-space: pre;           /* CSS 2.0 */
    white-space: pre-wrap;      /* CSS 2.1 */
    white-space: pre-line;      /* CSS 3.0 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla */
    white-space: -hp-pre-wrap;  /* HP Printers */
    word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE 5+ */
}
```

Source: http://perishablepress.com/wrapping-content/